# What is needed to run a VM of Windows 7 or 8 under Windows 8.1 64bit?

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, virtualization

I would like to create a virtual Windows 7 or 8 in my Windows 8.1 64 machine. Years ago I used Virtual PC to similar stuff and I know things have advanced a lot and I haven't kept up.

What are my choices now? Do I need VMWare? Windows can do this now? VirtualBox?

Comment: Any virtual machine software you want.  The three major options are VMWare, Hyper-V, VirtualBox.  We won't be able to recommend one over the other.  The requirements for Hyper-V are on Microsoft's website.

Comment: By the way, if you use VMWare or VirtualBox, you'll need Windows license. Don't know about Hyper-V

Comment: @tumchaaditya - You do.  But thats sort of a given.  Windows is not a free product.  There are trial virtual machines provided by Microsoft but those are only good for a small window of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can now use Hyper-V as your hypervisor for Windows 8 and 8.1 if you are looking for something native.

Just go to Programs > Windows Features and check Hyper-V.

[Here](http://www.howtogeek.com/76532/how-to-install-or-enable-hyper-v-virtualization-in-windows-8/) is an article detailing the process.

Answer (score 0):

[VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) has worked well for me under Windows and Linux host and guest. VMWare and VirtualBox run into the occasional issue, and it's easier to find help online for VirtualBox (based on empirical evidence, but I've used both quiet a bit).

VirtualBox was also the first to support a [64-bit guest running in a 32-bit host](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#intro-64bitguests) provided the CPU is 64-bit. Not relevant to the topic, but a neat fact.